# Best way of connecting ATMega32 to LCD with 16 pin

Tags: cables, ribbon-cable, socket

I am trying to control LCD [ADM2004D](http://amotec-display.com/pdf/ADM2004D.pdf) with ATMega32 AVR microcontroller. This type of LCD is 20x4 character, has 16 input and I am going to connect the main board to this LCD. I may need to disconnect it from the board sometimes. What is the best way of connection, in term of wires and male/female sockets.

I am thinking about ribbon cable. But there are so many types of cable and I am not familiar with their name. I look for something neat although I know everywire does the job.

Answer (score 1):

look for 0.1" pin headers on ebay, they can be easily cut to size using a pair of wire cutters or snips [pin header pairs on ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10-Pair-2-54mm-1X40-pin-header-Single-row-straight-male-female-for-Arduino-DIY-/281392015444)

Answer (score 0):

Do you remember when PC's had IDE harddisks and these were connected through wide ribbon cables ? I would use something like that ! But with less pins of course.

After some browsing on Ebay: [this cable + female connectors](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/IDC-16-Pin-Female-Female-Connector-Motherboard-Extension-Flat-Ribbon-Cable-19-/121659363737?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item1c53769199)
and on the PCBs either [these male connectors](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/10-Pcs-2mm-2x8-Pin-16-Pin-Straight-Male-Shrouded-PCB-Box-header-IDC-Connector-/171050187923?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27d362bc93) or simply [these](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/5PCS-2-54mm-2x40-Pin-Male-Double-Row-Pin-Header-Strip-/251083466855?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a75bda867) cut to size.

You can get them with different number of pins, just search. I would suggest to get a cable with the female connectors attached as attaching them yourself could be a challenge. And they're cheap anyway so why bother ;-)

Comment: Thank. one challenge is that I cant find single row of them.

Comment: There are so-called "Dupont" connectors which can work on a single row of pin-headers, for example: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/20pcs-2-54mm-to-2-54mm-Dupont-Wire-Cable-Connectors-4P-to-4P-Pin-Header-20cm-DG-/251721691617?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a9bc831e1.

But then you would have to use 4 x 4pins connectors to get 16 pins in total. I have not seen these in 16 pins versions.